# Why is my json unable to be converted to a string?

Tags: javascript

I have a function that gets remote JSON however that json I believe is poorly formatted so I can't use the JSON.stringify method on it. I think it's due to the apostrophe contained in some of it. I have no access to the sever. Is there a way I can parse and change the json so that all remote json pulled is formatted correctly?

this is the format now.

```
var jsonst = {"shows":[{"show_id":6387, "shownum":6387,"title":"The Protestant's  Dilemma","guest":"Devin Rose","category":"Non-Catholic","url":"http://www.catholic.com /radio/shows/the-protestants-dilemma-11565","audiourl":"http://www.catholic.com/sites /default/files/audio/radioshows/ca140331b.mp3","datetime":"1396317600","description":"
Devin Rose grew up a militant's<\/p>","thumbnailsmall":"http://www.catholic.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/profile_square_small/images/profilepics/a109aad8daa70ad8976ffc.L._V387899120_SX200_.jpg","thumbnaillarge":"http://www.catholic.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/profile_square_large/images/profilepics/a109aad8daa70ad8976ffc.L._V387899120_SX200_.jpg"}]}

var = jsonstring = JSON.stringify(jsonst);
alert(jsonstring);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typo:

```
var = jsonstring
```

Replace that with

```
var jsonstring
```

Also, I'm getting a `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` in your variable `jsonst`:

It seems like there's a newline character in your variable at:

```
"description":"
Devin Rose grew up ....
```

Remove the newline / linebreak before the `D` in `Devlin`, then the `jsonstring` variable will be filled just fine:

```
"{"shows":[{"show_id":6387,"shownum":6387,"title":"The Protestant's  Dilemma","guest":"Devin Rose","category":"Non-Catholic","url":"http://www.catholic.com /radio/shows/the-protestants-dilemma-11565","audiourl":"http://www.catholic.com/sites /default/files/audio/radioshows/ca140331b.mp3","datetime":"1396317600","description":"Devin Rose grew up a militant's</p>","thumbnailsmall":"http://www.catholic.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/profile_square_small/images/profilepics/a109aad8daa70ad8976ffc.L._V387899120_SX200_.jpg","thumbnaillarge":"http://www.catholic.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/profile_square_large/images/profilepics/a109aad8daa70ad8976ffc.L._V387899120_SX200_.jpg"}]}"
```

Comment: The illegal token is probably the backslash he uses and doesn't exist in his code

Comment: I'm afraid since I don't have server access, all json will come in like this. What can I do to the JSON to make sure it's formatted properly once I get it?

Comment: @Brandon: How exactly are you "getting" that data? JavaScript can handle newlines in strings, but that can be a hassle to manage.

Comment: @Cerbrus I'm getting the data using jquery's $.getJSON. I'm successfully receiving remote json, I just can't convert it to a string due to the issues above.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? (And if you do, what messages?)

Comment: @Cerbrus Well, I created an alert message with the variable containing the JSON.stringify(Jsonvar) method and Jsonvar contains the remote Json. However, the alert message shows up blank and I'm assuming that's due to the description key with the line break in it. I know other json will also have this kind of format issue, so I'm wondering if I can create code to modify the remote json received so that it doesn't have any line breaks.

Comment: I mean, are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50617/discussion-between-brandon-and-cerbrus)

Answer (score 0):

The value of the `description` key is throwing parse error. Dont have the line break in it. Instead of `"description": "
Devin Rose grew up a militant's</p>",`  just have `"description": "Devin Rose grew up a militant's</p>",`

Comment: I can't tell the difference between the two. Is it not being displayed here?